# Inequality involving square-integrable random variable

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

For any square-integrable ${X}$, show that

$\displaystyle {\bf P}(X \neq 0) \geq \frac{ ({\bf E} |X|)^2}{{\bf E}(|X|^2)}$.

**Attempt**: Equivalently, we want ${\bf P}(X \neq 0) {\bf E} (|X|^2) \geq ({\bf E} |X|)^2$. i.e. $({\bf E}1_{X \neq 0}) ({\bf E}|X|^2) \geq ({\bf E} |X|)^2$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have LHS = $(\|1_{X \neq 0}\|_2 \cdot \|X\|_2)^2 \geq |{\bf E}(X \cdot 1_{X \neq 0})|^2$, but the RHS is $({\bf E} |X|)^2$.

Comment: You can get the result by applying Cauchy-Schwarz to ${\bf E}(|X| \cdot 1_{X \neq 0})$ instead of ${\bf E}(X \cdot 1_{X \neq 0})$, plus using the fact that $|X| \cdot 1_{X \neq 0} = |X|$.

Comment: @WillowWisp It would be a good idea to post that as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: @WillowWisp: Thank you, indeed just one step away from the correct answer.